# Use the current calculated value from a group by sum to calculate another value in R using data.table

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data.table, aggregation

I'm trying to figure out how to use the value I just calculated to calculate the desired results in the table below. I know how to do this with `dplyr` but I'm stuck and trying to learn it while using `data.table`.

Essentially, I'm grouping the "Country" and summing their "Volume A" values for the new column "Desired Results" then using that new value and subtracting it from their respective "Volume B" data in their specific row.

```
Country | Volume A | Volume B | Desired Results    
Canada  | 100      | 50       | 250 
Canada  | 200      | 150      | 150 
USA     | 500      | 200      | 400 
France  | 0        | 0        | 0
USA     | 100      | 200      | 400
```

Comment: Why isn't `France` `0`, like `sum(0) - 0` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be 0. I will edit that. But that was because I was also trying to add a condition where if the sum is 0 then make it NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following where `NewCol` represents the desired results.

```
 df[,NewCol:=sum(Volume.A)-Volume.B,.(Country)][]
       Country Volume.A Volume.B Desired.Results NewCol
    1:  Canada      100       50             250    250
    2:  Canada      200      150             150    150
    3:     USA      500      200             400    400
    4:  France        0        0               0      0
    5:     USA      100      200             400    400
```